# How to scrap weapon mods in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a long scope for my laser musket but would like to scrap it and build a medium scope. Is there a way to scrap the actual long scope itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to scrap a mod is to scrap it along with a weapon.  Unfortunately if that musket is the only one you have you can't do that.  You'll have to just find and gather additional materials.

Comment: scrappign weapon destroys mods, not scraps them. There is no gain in scrapping modded weapon (and script-wise , it's apparently not quite possible)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to scrap just mods. Even if you drop them on the ground in a settlement, you just have the option to store them, not scrap them.

Comment: The user isn't talking about scrapping mods per se, but taking off mods in an existing weapon and re-building said weapon with a new and better mod, using materials from the scrap.

Comment: @Nelson Yes they are. If they aren't, the question needs a major edit.

Comment: @Nelson, Dallium is correct. I'm editing my question to make it clearer.